# Why am I getting an error when trying to save a list in Room database with the help of a type converter?

Tags: java, android, android-room, typeconverter

I want to store a list of Integer type in a Room database. For this I wrote a converter that looks like:

```
public class TypeConverter {

static Gson gson = new Gson();

@androidx.room.TypeConverter
public static List<Integer> stringToIntegerList(String data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {
    }.getType();

    return gson.fromJson(data, listType);
}

@androidx.room.TypeConverter
public static String someObjectListToString(List<Integer> someObjects) {
    return gson.toJson(someObjects);
}
}
```

Here is a part of the model class:

```
@TypeConverters(TypeConverter.class)
List<Integer> colors_ids;
```

And also a database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Flower.class}, version = 2)
@TypeConverters(TypeConverter.class)
```

And when I'm getting the list, I get an error:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

So the list is null. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

This is how I save an array to Room database:

```
dao.insert(new Flower(something, something, ..., new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.drawable.flower_clove_red); add(R.drawable.flower_clove_pink);}}));
```

Comment: Are you sure when you are population the list from your data source , it is not empty ?

Comment: I added an edit to the question. As long as my way of adding values to a new List is wrong.

Comment: What i want you to check  your list has data while being saved in your db if it contains data or not , because with typeconverter class i guess eveerything is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type converter class is alright. The problem was in my way of populating the database.